# How to start GL_Painter

Tags: opengl-3

I Hope that any one could help me to start doing this program in OpenGl
Write an OpenGL program (interactive program) that draw lines by clicking on the start point and then drag on the display window drawing area. 
Give the user a menu that (s)he choose from. The menu contains the following options: 
1- Clearing the display window. 
2- Choose a line drawing color which includes at least the colors (red, green, blue, black). 
3- Choose a line pattern which includes (dash, dot, dot-dash, solid lines). 
4- Choose a line thickness. (line width from 1 to 4). 
5- Quit the program.

Answer (score 0):

[AntTweakBar](http://www.google.pl/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBkQFjAA&url=http://www.antisphere.com/Wiki/tools%3aanttweakbar&rct=j&q=anttweakbar&ei=6AFMTsr6EMOM-wbpnqDrCA&usg=AFQjCNFymWF1aeBAhvHHmkTDZsPq1YltvA&sig2=Bgk9GSBXCMYMjLwKygswfw&cad=rja) is good minimalistic gui library and it integrate well with OpenGL (and you do not need much code).
[FreeGLUT](http://www.google.pl/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBwQFjAA&url=http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/&rct=j&q=freeglut&ei=UAJMTuDPOY2r-gba4bnrCA&usg=AFQjCNFxuJMxDbBQ1pjzFgNJ3tnfz7oTFg&sig2=I99vMFX8KHVWXZwqjaT8bw&cad=rja) will be good for windowing and mouse handling and it is also little code.
OpenGL.
[glBegin](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/) can be used for drawing lines.
[glCorol](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/) can be used for color (for choosing color use AntTweakBar).

If you need more help update question (you probably do not have rights to add comments, but you can edit your question).

PS From question I've draw assumption that you are beginner, hence level of my answer. I can go deeper if you like.

PSPS You do not need OpenGL to do this kind of stuff, but I assume that OpenGL is a requirement, right? Otherwise there are simpler solutions. Also clarify your question a bit (aspecially section about drawing lines, do you allow non-straight lines?).